# How do I set a value limit to a specific cell in Excel and add exceding entries to another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Over the past couple of days, I've had a hard time figuring out an issue that is supposed to be easy but I just can't wrap my head around.

To add some context, here's what I'm trying to do: I'm working on a class attendance sheet for teachers to keep track of students' attendance. In order to submit an entry, teachers will have to fill in 4 different cells: Date, Time, Lesson Content and Status (whether the class took place or the student didn't show up). I've added a dropdown to the Status cell so that the teacher chooses between predetermined codes (more on that soon).

I've also included a separate sheet where the school will register eventual replacement classes set up in alternative schedules, and it works in a similar fashion to the overall attendance sheet.

The third and last sheet in this workbook (where I'm having some issues) is an Hour Bank that is calculated based on the amount of cancellations versus the replacement classes the student scheduled and attended.

Here's where the issue kicks in. As I mentioned, I would like to create an Hour Bank System in order to store the classes that are "replaceable". This would be a relatively simple task, the only issue is that I also need to establish a cap (which is 8) so that the Hour Bank will not add beyond this specific number. The Hour Bank works fine, but the number doesn't go down immediately if the student exceeds the cap. If the student has, for instance, 2 classes over the cap, the Hour Bank Balance only goes down to 7 if I enter two replacement classes. However, I would like this particular cell to cap at 8 and go down as soon as a replacement class is registered, regardless of how many hours the student exceeds this cap.

Here are the elements contained in the 3rd sheet:

-Total Classes Given (D8): This part works fine. It's just a SUMIF with the specific code that means "Class ok". Code below:

```
=SUMIF(FREQ!F9:F106;"AR";FREQ!G9:G106)
```

-Total Client Cancellations (D11): This part also works fine. It's another SUMIF with the specific code meaning that the student didn't show up to class and didn't notify the school. These classes won't be accounted for in the hour bank. Code below:

```
=SUMIF(FREQ!F9:F106;"AC (Aluno)";FREQ!G9:G106)
```

-Total Replaceable Classes (D14): This part works fine. It's a combination of two SUMIFs with the codes that mean "Ok, student didn't come but we'll let them schedule a replacement class". Code below:

```
=SUMIF(FREQ!F9:F106;"PP";FREQ!G12:G109) + SUMIF(FREQ!F9:F106;"AC (Miles)";FREQ!G12:G109)
```

-Attendance Rate (D17): This part also works fine. It just shows the percentage of the classes that the student has attended up until the present moment. Code below:

```
=IF(D8>0; D8/FREQ!G107; "0,00%")
```

-Pending Replacement Classes (G8): This part works fine. It is a simple subtraction that calculates how many classes are pending (not considering the cap). This number goes down as I enter replacement classes in the second sheet of the workbook, and goes up as the teacher registers replaceable cancellations in the first sheet. Code below:

```
=D14-G11
```

-Given Replacement Classes (G11): This part works fine. It is a SUMIF that keeps track of how many replacement classes were given in total. Code:

```
=SUMIF(REPO!F9:F106;"AR";REPO!G9:G106)
```

-Exceding Hours (G14): This cell is broken. I'd like it to compute the amount of hours that the student has cancelled over the established cap. It does work when it comes to only computing the hours over the cap, but the issue is that it decreases as I enter replacement classes in the 2nd sheet of the workbook instead of subtracting them from the Hour Bank Balance which I will explain below.

```
=IF(G17=8; G8-8; 0)
```

-Hour Bank Balance (G17): This cell is broken, and it's the most important part of the entire workbook. I would like it to compute the replaceable classes up until the cap (which is 8) and make it go down immediately as a replacement class is registered. However, if the student has Exceding Hours (G14), the replacement classes are substracted from G14 instead of G17, which is what I wanted. The Hour Bank Balance (G17) will only go down if the Exceding Hours (G14) equals zero. Here's the code:

```
=IF((D14-G11)>8; 8; D14-G11)
```

I hope I was clear enough and I'm willing to provide screenshots if need be. I'm sure there's a problem with my maths or something, but I've been unable to spot it.

Please help a brother out!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that this formula might be what you’re looking for:

```
=IF((D14 - G11) > 8, 8, IF(D14 > 8, 8, D14) - G11)
```

The first part of this formula would give 8 as a value if `D14 - G11` is greater than 8; the second part of  this formula yields `D14 - G11` except for in cases where `D14` is greater than 8, then it gives `8 - G11`. Hopefully this is what you were looking for.